# Triggering this.props.dispatch in a test environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello I have a Jest / Enzyme test like this:

```
it('triggers checkbox onChange event', () => {
  const configs = {
    default: true,
    label: 'My Label',
    element: 'myElement',
  }
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckBox
      configs={configs}
    />
  )
  checkbox.find('input').simulate('click')
})
```

And a component that looks like this:

```
<div className="toggle-btn sm">
  <input 
    id={this.props.configs.element} 
    className="toggle-input round" 
    type="checkbox" 
    defaultChecked={ this.props.defaultChecked } 
    onClick={ e => this.onChange(e.target) }
  >
  </input>
</div>
```

Clicking on the `input` causes this method to be called:

```
this.props.dispatch(update(data))
```

It works okay in my browser, however when testing the `onClick` event I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function
```

How do I get `this.props.dispatch` to work in my test?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the entirety of the Checkbox component so that we can see how "this.props.dispatch(update(data))" comes into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `dispatch` as a prop in your test.

Modified code below:

```
it('triggers checkbox onChange event', () => {
  const configs = {
    default: true,
    label: 'My Label',
    element: 'myElement',
  }

  const dispatch = jest.fn();

  const props = {
    configs,
    dispatch
  }
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckBox
      {...props}
    />
  )
  checkbox.find('input').simulate('click')
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(update(data))
})
```